# The Chain Rule: Estimate the rate at which $θ$ is changing at that instant

Tags: calculus

Let $a$ and $b$ denote two sides of a triangle and let $θ$ denote the included angle. Suppose that $a$, $b$, and $θ$ vary with time in such a way that the area of the triangle remains constant. At a certain instant $a=5$ cm, $b=4$ cm, and $θ = π/6$ radians, and at that instant both $a$ and $b$ are increasing at a rate of 3 cm/s. Estimate the rate at which $θ$ is changing at that instant.

I've tried to solve it, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

$$
A=const=\frac{ab\sin{\theta}}{2}
$$
We know $\frac{da}{dt}=\frac{db}{dt}=3$. Then, differentiating the expression above:
$$
0=(a'b\sin{\theta})/2+(ab'\sin{\theta})/2+(ab\cos{\theta})\theta'/2
$$

Plug in the values:
$$
0=3*4/4+3*5/4+5*4*\frac{\sqrt3}{4}\theta' \Rightarrow \theta'=-\frac{9\sqrt3}{20}\text{rads/s}
$$